# flex box what is the correct way to maintain the empty space around children

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the flex box with children. I am look a solution to know that, is there a way to maintain the space around left, right, top, bottom around the children?

for my try: left and right is not even - how to solve it?
how to insure the same space applied in top and bottom of each children?

here is my code :

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.child{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:gray;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">01</div>
  <div class="child">02</div>
  <div class="child">03</div>
  <div class="child">04</div>
  <div class="child">05</div>
  <div class="child">06</div>
  <div class="child">07</div>
  <div class="child">08</div>
  <div class="child">09</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
  <div class="child">15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you should use child as containers and give padding to it and place content inside child

Comment: you are looking for `space-evenly`

Comment: @TemaniAfif - is not apply in the vertical side..

Comment: Not possible using flex properties. Perhaps css-grid though.

Comment: @ShirishMaharjan It won't work. The gap between the children will be twice the gap against parent's boundary. We won't achieve the same effect as css grid's gap.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done in a multi-line flex container, without lots of targeted code.

Whether margins or borders or padding are used for separation, you would have to provide different rules for the items adjacent to each other, adjacent to the container, and the first in each row.

Eventually, [the **`gap`** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) will be available for flexbox, allowing for uniform gutters. This property, however, is already supported in CSS Grid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">01</div>
  <div class="child">02</div>
  <div class="child">03</div>
  <div class="child">04</div>
  <div class="child">05</div>
  <div class="child">06</div>
  <div class="child">07</div>
  <div class="child">08</div>
  <div class="child">09</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
  <div class="child">12</div>
  <div class="child">13</div>
  <div class="child">14</div>
  <div class="child">15</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**RESULT**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">01</div>
    <div class="child">02</div>
    <div class="child">03</div>
    <div class="child">04</div>
    <div class="child">05</div>
    <div class="child">06</div>
    <div class="child">07</div>
    <div class="child">08</div>
    <div class="child">09</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
    <div class="child">11</div>
    <div class="child">12</div>
    <div class="child">13</div>
    <div class="child">14</div>
    <div class="child">15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

You need to set the number of columns using `.container` `width`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;

  width: 600px;

  display: flex;  
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;  
}

.child {
  border:1px solid #fff;
  width:100px;
  height:100px; 

  background:gray;   
}
```

Comment: still the around the container(green background) need to added with space